# Store ArrayList as persistent data android

Tags: android, arraylist, sharedpreferences

I have an arraylist. I need to store them as persistent data. How can I achieve this in android? Can shared preferences help?

Comment: You can use SharedPreferences but there you'll have to convert your data in some manner, since there is no `putArrayList()` method.

Comment: Put into shared preferences as already explained and discussed in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057845/save-arraylist-to-sharedpreferences)

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways depending on what the data is and what you plan to do with it. SharedPrefs, SQLite DB, and internal storage are all options. But like I said, it depends on what you are going to do. The **[Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)** explain all of these and you will need to decide what fits you best.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to use **SharedPreferences** for an **ArrayList** in a simple way (even in anyway) as there is not some `putObject()` or `putSerializable()` method in the [SharedPreference.Editor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html) class.

But there are several others [storage options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).